# How to add/append a row to a particular partition in the dask dataframe?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed, dask-dataframe

I want to append a row to a particular partition in dask dataframes. I have tried out many methods but none of them are possible. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance

I tried -

```
first_partition = df.partitions[0]
new_dd = first_partiton.append(row)
df.partitions[0] = new_dd
```

This doesn't work

I even tried to use map_partitions(), but even this function doesn't really help to get the metadata of the partition to modify a particular partition.

Is it possible to save the dataframe as parquet and modify just a particular parquet file and save it back? - I tried this, even this seems to not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `map_partitions` you can modify that particular partition.

Then create a new  frame by replacing the modified partition in the dataframe by switching to delayed objects, replacing the delayed object into the list, and then switching back to dask dataframe.

```py
def append_row_dict(df, row_dict):
    small_df = pd.DataFrame(row_dict)
    return df.append(small_df)
    
p_df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(0,10)})

dask_df = dd.from_pandas(p_df,npartitions=4)
part_to_change = 1

new_partion = dask_df.get_partition(part_to_change).map_partitions(append_row_dict,{'a':[-1]})
list_of_delayed = dask_df.to_delayed()

## we only have 1 delayed object for 1 partition
assert new_partion.npartitions==1
list_of_delayed[part_to_change]=new_partion.to_delayed()[0]

new_dask_df = dd.from_delayed(list_of_delayed, meta=dask_df._meta)
new_dask_df.get_partition(part_to_change).compute()
```

```py
    a
3   3
4   4
5   5
0   -1
```